# Using a proxy server with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, proxy, laravel-dusk

I have looked at the docks and searched the code but can find no mention of proxy support.

So it seems there is no native way to do this.

However I have found the following code that allows the headless chrome binary to be used with proxy settings.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

So my question is where can I add this code in Dusk to allow me to use a proxy server with Dusk and the headless chrome in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `tests/DuskTestCase.php` you will see fragment of code like this:

```
    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
```

so I believe you should change this into:

Comment: Is this answer removed?

Comment: This man knows how to build suspense.